# Given 4 linearly independent vectors in a vector space, what can be said about 4 other vectors, linear combinations of the previous vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. If vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ are linearly independent, what can be said about the vectors $2v_1+v_2+v_3$, $v_1-3v_2$, $v_4+v_3$, and $v_3-v_1$?

My guess is that the last four vectors are linearly independent among them. And I tried to prove this: $$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \text{ linearly independent} \Rightarrow \\(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+\alpha_4v_4 = 0,\ \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\in K \Rightarrow \alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=\alpha_4=0)$$
Here is my first problem. Because I do not know who $K$ is, can I say all those coefficients are equal to $0$? What if the field isn't made of numbers? Or can here $0$ simply denote the null element of $K$?

I then continue by letting $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_4\in K$ and finding that $$\beta_1(2v_1+v_2+v_3) +\beta_2(v_1-3v_2)+\beta_3(v_4+v_3)+\beta_4(v_3-v_1)=\\=v_1(2\beta_1+\beta_2-\beta_4)+v_2(\beta_1-3\beta_2)+v_3(\beta_1+\beta_3+\beta_4) + v_4\cdot\beta_3$$

Then, to check if those 4 vectors are linearly independent among them, I do the following: I equal the last relation to $0$ and, because $v_1,\cdots, v_4$ are linearly independent, that means that each coefficient (each paranthesis) must be $0$. Then I form a system of 4 equations and 4 unknowns and attempt to find that $\beta_1=\dots=\beta_4=0$. Here, again, I'm not sure if the $0$ is the null element of $K$. Indeed, after solving the system, all $\beta=0$.

Is this a correct approach/proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is not so bad, just missing a few key elements.

A field is a special example of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), which is a specific kind of algebraic object. All rings have two operations, "addition" $(+)$ and "multiplication" $(\cdot )$ which follow nice rules like distributivity. Also, every ring has a zero element $0$, which is the unique element satisfying $0+r=r+0=r$ for all $r$ in the ring. A vector space is something called a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)), which is useful, but not particularly important to your question.

For your first concern, yes, elements of $K$ need not be real or complex numbers at all. They can be elements of an arbitrary set, so long as the set and its operations satisfy the [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition). When we write "$0$", we don't necessarily mean the *number* $0$, but rather, the zero element of the field $K$.

The rest of your approach seems fine and pretty standard! Isolate the coefficients of $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$, set the whole thing equal to $0$, solve for the coefficients and show that they are equal to $0$. If you've done that, then you're done!

Answer (score 0):

"I do not know who $K$ is"

The set $K$ is a field, then you know that the elements of $K$ satisfy the field axioms.

"What if the field isn't made of numbers?" Your proof does not require that elements of $K$ need to be numbers. They can be anything that satisfies the field axioms.

"Or can here $0$ simply denote the null element of $K$?"

In the context above, $0$ denotes the additive identity of $K$.

"Is this a correct approach/proof?"

Yes, because it uses only the properties of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ and the assumption that $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in V$ are linearly independent.